# Swift Setting New Class Attributes Dynamically

Tags: python, swift

Preface: sorry I'm new to swift.
I am coming from Python, where you can simply do something like this:

```
>>> class TextField():
        self.empty = None
        
>>> TextField.prop = "prop"
>>> instance = TextField()
>>> instance.prop
'prop'
```

What I want to do in Swift is make my UITextFields all have a title property which is a string. I would like to be able to set it differently for each textfield instance in the code as well, which in Python terms would be the equivalent of doing instance.prop = "something else". Why does this simple concept seem to lead me to a labyrinth of protocols, extensions, designables, inspectables, and subclasses in Swift?? Maybe I am missing something obvious.

Comment: In Swift those are two different things TestField.prop is a static value and instance.prop a, well instance property. I think what you want is a instance property with a default value. I think you could extend UITesxtField and in the new initializer set the property.

Comment: Python is weakly typed. Swift is very strongly typed. They're just entirely different worlds, with different trade offs. I suggest checking out: https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/el2z9n/got_an_easy_question_ask_it_here_january_2020/ff7hdd6?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Right, but how would I do the above? I understand that swift is typed. That is not getting me any closer to solving my problem.

Comment: @oliverwebr when I do this I get "Extensions must not contain stored properties"

Comment: @inmanl My point wasn't to solve your problem, as you see it. My point was to make it clear that Swift and Python work in very different ways. The problem of "I can't put a new stored property on an object" can't be solved in Swift, because in Swift, we don't do that. Pythons objects are just plain dictionaries under the hood, with values keyed by their variable names. Swift's types are actual regions of memory, laid out directly (with no notion of variable, at run-time). You can't add a new variable to an existing object, because that would change its memory layout.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica okay. telling me my problem can't be solved in swift is actually helpful. Thanks I guess. I hate this language.

Comment: In python, you can add as many fields as you want to an object, because each object's underlying dictionary is heap allocated, and has the freedom to heap allocate as many buckets as are required to fit the fields of the object. This is "convenient" (though not as good of a thing as it may appear, it has a lot of drawbacks), but isn't very performant. Whereas Swift's objects are consecutive chunks of memory, which store variables in-line. They have a fixed sized, because that's necessary information for the compiler to know how to pass them around, e.g. to a function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216960/discussion-between-alexander-reinstate-monica-and-inmanl).